# Multiple http requests, process only those that respond within a time limit

Tags: c#, .net

I have backend on .net core. I need to send in parallel multiple http requests with time limit. By time limit, I mean that these requests have for example 500 ms to get response from requested sources. So, **the question is how to limit request time and process only those request which received the response from source.**

Answer (score -1):

This two links cover evetything about my question.

1. [Process asynchronous tasks as they complete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/start-multiple-async-tasks-and-process-them-as-they-complete?pivots=dotnet-6-0)
2. [Cancel async tasks after a period of time](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/cancel-async-tasks-after-a-period-of-time)

There is this code sample

```cs
static async Task Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Application started.");

    try
    {
        s_cts.CancelAfter(3500);

        await SumPageSizesAsync();
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nTasks cancelled: timed out.\n");
    }
    finally
    {
        s_cts.Dispose();
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Application ending.");
}
```

Comment: Please put the body of your answer in your answer. Link only answers are discouraged because they are likely to break when the 3rd party (Microsoft) changes their website.